# Why use python process rdd data so slow? Where does the performance bottle-neck of pyspark lie?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using pyspark to process data in local mode. The data is stored on HDFS and the total size of the six file data is 789MB.

My code is as below:

```
df=spark.read.option("header",True).csv(source_dir+'/*.csv')
df.show()
ndf=df.rdd.repartition(40).map(lambda row:preprocess_row(row)).toDF(schema=schema)
ndf.write\
    .partitionBy("subject_seg_id") \
    .mode('overwrite') \
    .option("encoding", "utf-8") \
    .option("header", True) \
    .format("csv") \
    .save(target_dir)

def preprocess_row(row, is_debug=True,file_type="local"):
  start=time.time()
  empty = ('', '', -1.0, -1.0, 0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
  subject_seg_id = row['subject_seg_id']
  if '/' in subject_seg_id:
     subject_seg_id=subject_seg_id.split('/')
     subject_seg_id=[f for f in subject_seg_id if '=' in f]
     if len(subject_seg_id)==1:
         subject_seg_id=subject_seg_id[0].split('=')[-1]
   abp_ws = row["ABP_ws"]
   res_tuple = inner_process(abp_ws, empty)
   end=time.time()
   duration=int(end-start)
   return (subject_seg_id, row['window_id'], row['PPG_ws'], row['ABP_ws'],duration,) + res_tuple

def inner_process(abp_ws, empty):
if not isinstance(abp_ws,type(None)):
    data = abp_ws.split('-')
    data = [w for w in data if w != '']
    data = [float(d) for d in data]
    data = np.array(data)
    peak_idx, peaks = peak_detection(data)
    valley_idx, bottoms = peak_detection(-1.0 * data)
    if not isinstance(bottoms, type(None)):
        bottoms = [-1.0 * d for d in bottoms]
    sbp_tuple = stats(peaks, peak_idx, empty)
    dbp_tuple = stats(bottoms, valley_idx, empty)
    snr = float(SNR_denoise(data, fs=125, n_fft=8192))
    return (snr,) + sbp_tuple + dbp_tuple
else:
    return (0.0,)+empty+empty


def stats(data, idxs, empty_res):
if not isinstance(data, type(None)) and len(data) != 0:
    idxs = ','.join([str(d) for d in idxs])
    d_raw = ','.join([str(d) for d in data])
    d_max = float(np.amax(data))
    d_min = float(np.amin(data))
    d_num = len(data)
    d_mean = float(np.mean(data))
    d_medium = float(np.median(data))
    d_range = d_max - d_min
    d_std = float(np.std(data))
    return (idxs, d_raw, d_max, d_min, d_num, d_mean, d_medium, d_range, d_std)
return empty_res


def SNR_denoise(raw_data, fs, n_fft, b=0.5, a=5):
  no_DC_data = raw_data - np.mean(raw_data)
  f, power_spectrum_data = signal.welch(no_DC_data, fs=fs, window='hann', nfft=n_fft)
  # The frequency components of b ~ a Hz were selected
  df_f = pd.Series(f)
  lf_index = df_f[df_f.values >= b].index[0]
  hf_index = df_f[df_f.values >= a].index[0]
  lf_psd = np.sum(power_spectrum_data[0: lf_index + 1])
  best_psd = np.sum(power_spectrum_data[lf_index + 1: hf_index + 1])
  hf_psd = np.sum(power_spectrum_data[hf_index + 1: int(n_fft / 2)])
  snr = best_psd / (lf_psd + hf_psd)
  return snr
```

The logic is very simple, the custom function `preprocess_row` is the function that extracts info from the row. The performance of the code is so poor. Just processing about 800MB of data takes more than half an hour in local mode. I have 40 cores on the server. This is unacceptable.

Can anyone help to analyze my code, or give some suggestions? The spark version is 3.4.0

I'm using this code to check the code logic. But if the performance is so poor, how can I process about 20,000 files in standalone mode? The time consumption must be unacceptable.

[image]

[image: time comsumption of data]

for local test, 5985 pieces of records, the time consumption stats is:
[image]
[image: Data looks very imbalance, the longest time consumption is 38min for completed task]

Comment: We're missing a very important piece of code: `preprocess_row`. If this piece is written very inefficiently, it will completely explain your issues. Can you please share it?

Comment: The input of preprocess_row is the dataframe row, and I use one column of data to extract information. The column is a long string, I first split the string, then convert the item in the list into float. Then I detect peaks indexes,vpeaks values and bottoms indexes and values of the list. And I calculate the SNR, statistical values such as max,min,mean,std of peak values and bottom values. The logic is not complex.

Comment: Please post the code in here. We can't help you to say what is inefficient if you don't share what the exact calculations are.

Comment: I've added all dependent functions' code. Please help to analyze the performance problem.

Comment: is your process using all nodes? the performance can be poor if the code runs only on the driver node... given other nodes don't have the functions.

Comment: if run local, the performance is poor. If run on cluster, the performance is also poor. I only have one script file. All functions are written in this file. And there are about 100 tasks running in parallel.

Comment: By trying over and over again, it seems that the performance can't be improved. The cores of the cluster are not enough. And the calculation is complicated.

Comment: At last, I tried to process data in batch, so that each batch have sufficient resources. Then the data is processed. Thanks a lot

Comment: Also, save data in parquet mode can also improve the performance